# Print routes from tickets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

Today I encountered a question which I am not able to solve.

A frequent traveler collects all his travel tickets. 
A ticket has only 2 attributes, Start Journey Location name and Destination Name. Example from Delhi to NY. 
At the end of the year, the traveler gets all his tickets together and tries to map his journey across the year. Print his probable travel route in a readable format. He does not remember his start location.  he can visit a location multiple times, and can also go back and forth a place several times.

Initially i thought that it could simply be solved by making a graph(ticket-A to B means a directed edge A->B) and using a simple Depth first traversal from a node with indegree 0(??). but then I realized that its not the correct way to get solution as it could print a random unconnected route.
Please suggest a correct way to proceed.

Comment: Search for "eulerian path"

Comment: If we assume that all travel has a related ticket (i.e. he didn't fly to Chicago, then drive to New York and fly to Boston), then if he flew from A to B, the next journey must start at B. Maintaining that restriction will prevent you from creating a random, unconnected, path.

Comment: @JimMischel suppose if we are at city B currently and have many tickets which involves B as destination(a1-b, a2-b, a3-b...) as well as source(b-c1,b-c2,b-a1,...) now how to judge, being on city B, that which path taking first will lead to a connected route(connected means end and start point should always remain the same).

Comment: @DeepankarSingh: I was just telling you how to avoid a random, unconnected, route. The rest of the job sounds like a dynamic programming problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check whether your graph has an Eulerian trail or an Eulerian cycle.

> A directed graph has an **Eulerian cycle** if and only if every vertex has
>   equal in degree and out degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero
>   degree belong to a single strongly connected component. Equivalently,
>   a directed graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if it can be
>   decomposed into edge-disjoint directed cycles and all of its vertices
>   with nonzero degree belong to a single strongly connected component.
>
> A directed graph has an **Eulerian trail** if and only if at most one vertex
>   has (out-degree) − (in-degree) = 1, at most one vertex has (in-degree)
>   − (out-degree) = 1, every other vertex has equal in-degree and
>   out-degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a
>   single connected component of the underlying undirected graph.

If your graph has an Eulerian cycle, you can start your DFS from any arbitrary node and you can be sure that your path will be correct.

If your graph has an Eulerian trail, first find the node with `(out-degree) − (in-degree) = 1` and call it `source` and find the node with `(in-degree) − (out-degree) = 1` and call it `sink`. You should start your DFS from `source` and avoid going to `sink` as much as possible. It means whenever there is an option between going to node `sink` and some other node you should go the other node and use the `sink` node only when you have no other option (not exactly true but makes it simpler). This way you can be sure that you end up with the correct trail.